# Linking PyQt buttons with Python actions

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I'm having trouble getting buttons in a GUI laid out in QT Designer and converted into a python script to do anything when clicked.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from punchmenuui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.closemenubutton.clicked.connect(self.closemenu)

def closemenu(self):
    sys.exit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, its simple. I have a button specified in the layout .py file and I'm trying to capture the "clicked" signal from it and have that trigger a clean exit event. The trouble is: nothing seems to achieve that.
I've tried both the newer and older style PyQt signal/slot bindings to no avail.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses so far guys. I've tried every combination of all of your answers, but none of them work so far. My current code for the launcher .py script stands as:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog
from punchmenuui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.closemenubutton.clicked.connect(self.closemenu)

    def closemenu():
        sys.exit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the script for the QT-Designed ui is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'punchmenu.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Mar 10 01:30:31 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(480, 320)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 0, 481, 301))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QTabBar::scroller { /* the width of the scroll buttons */ width: 50px; } "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.hometab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.hometab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("hometab"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.hometab)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 0, 371, 231))
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("vtc punch logo.jpg")))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.hometab)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.flipscreenbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.hometab)
        self.flipscreenbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.flipscreenbutton.setFont(font)
        self.flipscreenbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("flipscreenbutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.hometab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.powertab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.powertab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("powertab"))
        self.groupBox_5 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.powertab)
        self.groupBox_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_5.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_5"))
        self.restartbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_5)
        self.restartbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 181, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.restartbutton.setFont(font)
        self.restartbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("restartbutton"))
        self.shutdownbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_5)
        self.shutdownbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 181, 111))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.shutdownbutton.setFont(font)
        self.shutdownbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("shutdownbutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.powertab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.lanipconfigtab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.lanipconfigtab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lanipconfigtab"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.lanipconfigtab)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.dhcpbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.dhcpbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 201, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.dhcpbutton.setFont(font)
        self.dhcpbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dhcpbutton"))
        self.staticbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.staticbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 80, 201, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.staticbutton.setFont(font)
        self.staticbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("staticbutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.lanipconfigtab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.wificonfigtab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.wificonfigtab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wificonfigtab"))
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.wificonfigtab)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 481, 281))
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollArea"))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 477, 277))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.groupBox_9 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 471, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_9.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_9"))
        self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.groupBox_9)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 451, 241))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.scanforaccesspointsbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.scanforaccesspointsbutton.setFont(font)
        self.scanforaccesspointsbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scanforaccesspointsbutton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scanforaccesspointsbutton)
        self.connectwifibutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.connectwifibutton.setFont(font)
        self.connectwifibutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("connectwifibutton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.connectwifibutton)
        self.disconnectwifibutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.disconnectwifibutton.setFont(font)
        self.disconnectwifibutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("disconnectwifibutton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.disconnectwifibutton)
        self.erasestoredwifinetworksbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.erasestoredwifinetworksbutton.setFont(font)
        self.erasestoredwifinetworksbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("erasestoredwifinetworksbutton"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.erasestoredwifinetworksbutton)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.wificonfigtab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.captivportallogintab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.captivportallogintab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("captivportallogintab"))
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.captivportallogintab)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 481, 271))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("http://www.briancourt.co.uk/")))
        self.webView.setZoomFactor(0.40000000596)
        self.webView.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform|QtGui.QPainter.TextAntialiasing)
        self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.captivportallogintab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.wifiapconfigtab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.wifiapconfigtab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wifiapconfigtab"))
        self.groupBox_4 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.wifiapconfigtab)
        self.groupBox_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_4.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_4"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.wifiapconfigtab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.vpnconfigtab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.vpnconfigtab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vpnconfigtab"))
        self.groupBox_6 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.vpnconfigtab)
        self.groupBox_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_6.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_6"))
        self.disconnectvpnbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_6)
        self.disconnectvpnbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 211, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.disconnectvpnbutton.setFont(font)
        self.disconnectvpnbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("disconnectvpnbutton"))
        self.connectvpnbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_6)
        self.connectvpnbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 150, 211, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.connectvpnbutton.setFont(font)
        self.connectvpnbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("connectvpnbutton"))
        self.switchtotcpbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_6)
        self.switchtotcpbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 211, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.switchtotcpbutton.setFont(font)
        self.switchtotcpbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("switchtotcpbutton"))
        self.switchtoudpbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_6)
        self.switchtoudpbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 211, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.switchtoudpbutton.setFont(font)
        self.switchtoudpbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("switchtoudpbutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.vpnconfigtab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.statusdisplaytab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.statusdisplaytab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusdisplaytab"))
        self.lanipbox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.statusdisplaytab)
        self.lanipbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 461, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lanipbox.setFont(font)
        self.lanipbox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lanipbox"))
        self.lanipshow = QtGui.QLabel(self.lanipbox)
        self.lanipshow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 451, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.lanipshow.setFont(font)
        self.lanipshow.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lanipshow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lanipshow"))
        self.groupBox_2 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.statusdisplaytab)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 461, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_2"))
        self.wifiipshow = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
        self.wifiipshow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 451, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.wifiipshow.setFont(font)
        self.wifiipshow.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.wifiipshow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("wifiipshow"))
        self.groupBox_3 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.statusdisplaytab)
        self.groupBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 461, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_3"))
        self.vpnipshow = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_3)
        self.vpnipshow.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 451, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.vpnipshow.setFont(font)
        self.vpnipshow.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vpnipshow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("vpnipshow"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.statusdisplaytab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.softwareupdatetab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.softwareupdatetab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("softwareupdatetab"))
        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(self.softwareupdatetab)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 311, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(self.softwareupdatetab)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 40, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
        self.groupBox_7 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.softwareupdatetab)
        self.groupBox_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 9, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_7.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_7"))
        self.checkforupdatebutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_7)
        self.checkforupdatebutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 90, 231, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.checkforupdatebutton.setFont(font)
        self.checkforupdatebutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkforupdatebutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.softwareupdatetab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.devmenutab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.devmenutab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("devmenutab"))
        self.groupBox_8 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.devmenutab)
        self.groupBox_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 10, 461, 261))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox_8.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_8"))
        self.closemenubutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_8)
        self.closemenubutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.closemenubutton.setFont(font)
        self.closemenubutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("closemenubutton"))
        self.iteratenewpunch = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_8)
        self.iteratenewpunch.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 421, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.iteratenewpunch.setFont(font)
        self.iteratenewpunch.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("iteratenewpunch"))
        self.cloneexistingpunchbutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_8)
        self.cloneexistingpunchbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 421, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.cloneexistingpunchbutton.setFont(font)
        self.cloneexistingpunchbutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("cloneexistingpunchbutton"))
        self.restartmenubutton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_8)
        self.restartmenubutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 40, 191, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.restartmenubutton.setFont(font)
        self.restartmenubutton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("restartmenubutton"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.devmenutab, _fromUtf8(""))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(9)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Punch Menu", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Beta 2", None))
        self.flipscreenbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Flip Screen", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.hometab), _translate("MainWindow", "Home", None))
        self.groupBox_5.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Action", None))
        self.restartbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Restart", None))
        self.shutdownbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Shutdown", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.powertab), _translate("MainWindow", "Power", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Connection Type", None))
        self.dhcpbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DHCP (Auto)", None))
        self.staticbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Static (Manual)", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.lanipconfigtab), _translate("MainWindow", "LAN IP Config", None))
        self.groupBox_9.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Action", None))
        self.scanforaccesspointsbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Scan for Access Points", None))
        self.connectwifibutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect Wifi", None))
        self.disconnectwifibutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Disconnect Wifi", None))
        self.erasestoredwifinetworksbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Erase Stored Wifi Networks", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.wificonfigtab), _translate("MainWindow", "Wifi IP Config", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.captivportallogintab), _translate("MainWindow", "Captive Portal Login", None))
        self.groupBox_4.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Feature Not Yet Implemented", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.wifiapconfigtab), _translate("MainWindow", "Wifi A/P Config", None))
        self.groupBox_6.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Action", None))
        self.disconnectvpnbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Disconnect VPN", None))
        self.connectvpnbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect VPN", None))
        self.switchtotcpbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch to TCP", None))
        self.switchtoudpbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Switch to UDP", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.vpnconfigtab), _translate("MainWindow", "VPN Config", None))
        self.lanipbox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "LAN IP", None))
        self.lanipshow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP GOES HERE", None))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "WIFI IP", None))
        self.wifiipshow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP GOES HERE", None))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "VPN IP", None))
        self.vpnipshow.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "IP GOES HERE", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.statusdisplaytab), _translate("MainWindow", "Status Display", None))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Current Software Version:", None))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "016", None))
        self.groupBox_7.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Software Version", None))
        self.checkforupdatebutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check For Update", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.softwareupdatetab), _translate("MainWindow", "Software Update", None))
        self.groupBox_8.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Action", None))
        self.closemenubutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Menu", None))
        self.iteratenewpunch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Iterate and Deploy New Punch!", None))
        self.cloneexistingpunchbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clone Existing Punch!", None))
        self.restartmenubutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Restart Menu", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.devmenutab), _translate("MainWindow", "Dev Menu", None))

from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
```

Does this help nail-down what isn't doing what it should be?

Comment: Generally you should use `self.close()` instead of `sys.exit()` to close your main window.

Answer (score 0):

Your `closemenu` function needs to be part of your class.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.closemenubutton.clicked.connect(self.closemenu)

    # Notice this has been brought into the class
    def closemenu(self):
        sys.exit()
```

---

You didn't provide your UI file, so I can't perform an exact test, but I can show you that this works with a simple example:

This code creates a single button:

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.closebutton = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit', self)
        self.closebutton.clicked.connect(self.exit_button)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.closebutton)

    def exit_button(self):
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It looks like this:

[image: Example Button]

When the button is clicked, the application closes with an exit status of `0` (a clean exit)

```
C:\Sandbox>python exit_button.py
C:\Sandbox>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Comment: The close menu doesn't have to be apart of the class, but he would have to reword it to ''self.closemenubutton.clicked.connect(closemenu)'' and remove self as a parameter for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the underlying problem was, I was able to remedy it by switching to using Eric IDE in conjunction with Qt designer and following this tutorial: http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/tutorials/MiniBrowser/index.html to learn about the benefits of a development "environment" over what amounts to basically notepad that I was using before!

Defining actions is so much easier when you can see the handles you're attaching them too!
Other noobs reading this - follow that guide, it got me off the ground with object orientated programming and GUIs.